# php email form validation code

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm creating a subscribe page and I have some problems with email verification.

For now I have 3 files index.php, send.php and config.php

Now the part for form looks like this;  index.php looks like this:

```
      <div id="mc_embed_signup">
           <form action="send.php" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

              <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="El. Paštas" required>


              <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_cdb7b577e41181934ed6a6a44_e65110b38d" value=""></div>

              <!-- <div class="clear"> --><input type="submit" value="SEKITE" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"><!-- </div> -->

           </form>
        </div>
```

It connects with send.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$con = mysql_connect($dhost, $duser, $dpass) or die('neimanoma prisijungti prie db serverio'); 
mysql_select_db($dname) or die('neimanoma prisijungti prie duombazes'); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

$val = mysql_query('select 1 from `Prenumeratoriai_2015`');
if($val == FALSE){
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE Prenumeratoriai_2015 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY( id ),";
  $sql .= "email VARCHAR(255),";
  $sql .= ")";

  $result = mysql_query ("$sql");
  if(!($result))
     echo "<BR><font color=red>Error; ".mysql_errno()."; error description: </font>".mysql_error();
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `vilmantasz_stovykla1`.`Prenumeratoriai_2015` (  `email` ) values ( '".$_REQUEST["EMAIL"]."' )";

$result = mysql_query ("$sql");
if(!($result))
   echo "<BR><font color=red>Registracija nesėkminga, bandykite dar karta.</font>";
   header("Location: http://www.noriufotografuotis.com/subscribe/Prenumeracija_sekminga.html");

?>
```

And I have few problems:

1. I don't know how to make send.php check if the email is in right form
   (because now if you enter test.test it will add this to  Database, and I want it to check if the entry is email).
2. how to check if the email is not already in the list to avoid duplicating?
3. after pressing subscribe ("sekite") button it opens new tab (registracijasekminga.html <- translate "registrationsuccesful.php")
   But how to make it open in the same tab?
4. how to make it show that the email is incorrect or that is already in the list not in new page but near the entry form?

Comment: 4 questions in 1, *too broad*.

Comment: I know, but as far as im new here its hard for me to finish my work... :/

Comment: Do take the time to learn basic HTML and PHP/SQL. You've an answer below that covers it all pretty much.

Comment: Welcome! 1) Try searching for each individual question you have first. Then, if you can't find it, ask! 2) Make sure you [escape inputs from the internet](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1:- if( filter_var( $_POST['email'] ,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ) { insert }

Ans 2:- Select * from Prenumeratoriai_2015 where email like '%".$_POST['email']."%'. If you don't get rows for this query, then you can insert.

Ans 3 :- remove "target="_blank"" from the form

Ans 4 :- Use header function to get back to same page with extra parameter in the url, which acts as a flag for error.

Comment: Could you please show me where should i add it to my code?
Because i tried to add it in different ways and it's not working ://

Answer (score 0):

1)You can use str_pos or fliter_validate_email for checking if the email format is correct.

2)

```
$stt = $conn -> prepare ("SELECT ID from <Table name> where <column_name> = :email");
$stt -> bindValue('email', $_POST["email"]);
$stt -> execute();
$id = $stt -> fetchColumn();
if(empty($id)) {
// No such email exists
} else {
// User has already subscribed
}
```

3)Remote target="_blank".

4)Try redirecting back like:

```
header('Location: login.php?param=value');
```

Add this to the login.php

```
if(isset($_GET["param"])) {
if($_GET["param"] == "requrired_value") {
//Code to inform the user that provided email is incorrect.
}
}
```

Comment: So my send.php should look like this? s23.postimg.org/lkr19irvv/image.jpg

Comment: Are you new to php and programming? Seems so.

Remove the "<" and ">" in the prepare statement.
Check if the $_POST["email"] corresponds to your input field name in the login page.

Replace the "//" line with the code you need.